# Log4j2 - Date is not working in new format

Tags: java, log4j2

Recently I have upgraded the log4j which made me change in XML level
And I did as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- An appender for the console -->
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %m%n%ex"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="fatal">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But after changing format as log4j2, the Data is not printing as expected like "2019-07-26 17:53:28,261" instead it displays as "%d".

```
%d DEBUG [main]  new  Test 
%d DEBUG [main]  new  Test1
%d DEBUG [main]  new  Test2
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Here is one that I use - you can probably adjust yours based on this: `pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} whatever else you need..."`

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/layouts.html), for reference. See the `d{pattern}` section.

Comment: yes, Thank. But as per the Documentation ```If, no date format specifier is given then ISO8601 format is assumed.```.  and for my case still, it is %d

Comment: That's a good point - and `%d` on its own is working for me, as per the document. For example `2020-04-08 11:54:08,197`. So that suggests something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Issue. The actual problem is the changes in Log4j2.xml (src/main/resources/log4j2.xml) is not get reflected in the Generated file (target/classes/log4j2.xml) in which the Pattern of date is wrong "%%d".

Comment: _...not get reflected in the Generated file..._ Can you perhaps edit your answer, and clarify what that means? What "generated" file are you referring to? (And what you did to fix it?) This is just to help other people in the future who may visit your question. Glad you found the answer, by the way!